# Prestashop 1.6 not loading at all

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm having an issue with a PS 1.6 installation, it's currently running on PHP 5.6 (if I move to PHP 7 it does not even try to load), and whenever I try to load the site it keeps loading, crashing after a minute:

http://gemasbisuteriacr.com/web/

This is the error log content:

PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in gemasbisuteriacr.com/web/modules/posstaticfooter/models/Staticfooter.php on line 83

However it's not an error but a notice... any idea on what may be happening or how can I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: Are you running PrestaShop v1.6.1.24 or an older version? Can you turn on `_PS_MODE_DEV_` in `/config/defines.inc.php`? It seems the `posstaticfooter` module you are using is coming from your template, and the author indicates it should be compatible with PHP 5.2+.

Comment: Thanks! The site is 1.6.1.3, I just activated the debug mode and deactivated the posstaticfooter module. I'm getting a 504 Gateway Time-Out error, and no error is being displayed in the browser. Does the debug mode writes on any log?

Comment: let's switch to the PrestaShop SO chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192800/prestashop

Answer (score 0):

Only the latest version of PrestaShop 1.6 is compatible with php 7.0 or 7.1, not 7.2 and not 7.3, therefore, its logical to think that also some of your modules are NOT 100% compatible with php 7 and need to be updated or fixed.

Comment: OP mentioned he's running PHP 5.6

Answer (score 0):

try desactivate or delete module `posstaticfooter`

Regards